# what is iskeyword used in Abbrevation in VIM

Tags: vim

In the vim help doc, it says that The `full-id` type Abbreviation consists entirely of keyword characters (letters and characters from `iskeyword` option). 
And the `iskeyword` entry says that string:

```
Vim default for MS-DOS and Win32
"@,48-57,_,128-167,224-235"
```

otherwise:  `"@,48-57,_,192-255"`

what does it mean? what are `48-57, 128-167,224-235`?
Is `@` one of the character? But I tried something like `@tt`, it doesn't work!

And the vim doc give examples  `-1` under the entry `full-id` indicates that `-` is one of the keyword. But I tried on my vim. And found that

`-1` works

`-11` doesn't work

It seems that in my vim the `-` is treated as a non-keyword character. What is wrong? I didn't set any custom iskeyword.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"@,48-57,_,128-167,224-235"` are characters and ranges from your encoding table. Take a look to the ASCII table and you will see that the range `48-57` are numbers from `0` to `9`. For characters above `128` you will probably need to go to the Unicode table, see it with `set encoding?`. `@` is special and adds all alphabetic characters.

About the example that don't work for you: There are three kinds of abbreviations, `full-id`, `end-id` and `non-id`. So any abbreviation must fit in one of those groups. `-1` works and it is an `end-id`. It ends with a character of `isKeyword`. `-11` not, because it has another keyword after the first one, it neither is a `full-id` because `-` is not a keyword.

Comment: Well, I don't know if you are right or not. There is many strange characters there between 128-167 in unicode table or extended ASCII. But I tried copy the character from the table.For example using Euro sign which is correspond to 128 to begin the abbreviation like €jj, But I still got an error E474.

Comment: And in terms of "-1", it is used as an example under the "full-id" entry in vim doc. See http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#abbreviations    So I can only assume that this example is wrong in this official vim doc.

Answer (score 1):

Let's examine `-11` based on the rules of `:help abbreviation`:

1. It is not a full-id because it contains `-`, which is not included in your `iskeyword` option value.
2. It is not an end-id, because according to the documentation all the characters other than the last one must not be keyword characters, and the middle `1` is.
3. It is not a non-id, because it ends in a keyword character.

If you wish for the dash to be a keyword character, you must included it in `iskeyword` with the appropriate value for the encoding you are using (45 in UTF-8, etc).